# Git Pull on repo when a commit is pushed to GitHub

Tags: git, github, githooks

I'm currently working between a development machine (A) and a remote development server (B) that I have to ssh into.

Im looking for a way to add a githook to my repo so that when I commit on A and push to github I want the repo on B to automatically pull from origin so that its always up to date.

It seems like a small thing but I have to type git pull hundreds of times a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script and place it as `hooks/post-receive` (don't forget `chmod +x`). Push your ssh key to machine B (see https://serverfault.com/a/241593/124523).

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@development.server 'cd project/dir && git pull && exit'
```

Comment: I had something similar. At this point I don't believe that post-receive is being executed at all.

Comment: Post-receive hook should be where the bare repository is (Github for example)

Comment: Ok that would definitely be an issue with what Im doing. I will try this tomorrow and update.